# Display unrendered HTML in PRE tags (like bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a style guide that contains all the components of a large website (text, buttons, tables, banners, footers, modals etc). Under each component I want to display the components mark-up in PRE tag as unrendered html. The idea is that a developer can select and/or copy the mark-up and use it.

An example of this would be Bootstrap - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons

[image]

I know I can escape out the tags (`&lt;` instead of <) but as I have a lot of components its going to take too long. I was wondering if anyone had heard of a plugin that might do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you would need to escape HTML entities in `pre` and `code` tags. Most programming languages have a function to do this, but if you are working by hand it is probably easier to use [an online encoder tool](http://www.google.com/search?q=online+html+escape+tool).